# What options are there to do a mail merge?

Tags: windows, thunderbird, plugins, mail-merge

I tried (and failed) to do a mail merge to send a generic(ish) mail merge to send a bunch of emails using [Thunderbird](http://en-gb.www.mozillamessaging.com/en-GB/thunderbird/) with the [the Mail Merge addon](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Mail_merge) but couldn't get it to work.

What other options exist to quickly and simply set up a mail merge under windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft Word does e-mail merges. You can take the list of recipients from an Excel document, another word document or Outlook contacts, etc.

Comment: Accepted - that's what I did in the end!